# OCR Line detecting

Tags: c#, opencv, ocr, hough-transform

I am trying to detectect the bounding box of sentences in an Image. I am using Emgu OpenCV in C# using HougLinesP method to extract lines, but I am obviously doing something wrong. I have looked at many examples and [estimate the skew level with houghLines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12214556/estimate-the-skew-level-with-houghlines) is pretty much what I am trying to do.

Using that sample image I do some pre-processing (Thresholding, canny, ect) and end  up with http://snag.gy/sWCuO.jpg, but then when I do HoughLines and draw the lines on the original image, I get http://snag.gy/ESKmR.jpg .

Here is an extract of my code:

```
using (MemStorage stor = new MemStorage())
{
    Image<Hsv, byte> imgHSV = new Image<Hsv, byte>(bitmap);
    Image<Gray, Byte> gray = imgHSV.Convert<Gray, Byte>().PyrDown().PyrUp();

CvInvoke.cvCanny(gray, EdgeMap, 100, 400, 3);
    IntPtr lines = CvInvoke.cvHoughLines2(EdgeMap, stor,
        Emgu.CV.CvEnum.HOUGH_TYPE.CV_HOUGH_PROBABILISTIC, 1, Math.PI / 360, 10, 
        gray.Width / 4, 20);

   Seq<LineSegment2D> segments = new Seq<LineSegment2D>(lines, stor);
   ar = segments.ToArray();

}

Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(OriginalImage);
foreach (LineSegment2D line in ar)
{
    g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Blue), 
        new Point(line.P1.X, line.P1.Y), 
        new Point(line.P2.X, line.P2.Y));
}
g.Save();
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try two approaches:

1- Utilize the frequency domain. Example [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/discrete_fourier_transform/discrete_fourier_transform.html)

2- After pre-processing, extract the contours, collect all the points (or at least collect all points that are not black); find the minimum bounding rectangle with its angle. Example [here](http://felix.abecassis.me/2011/10/opencv-bounding-box-skew-angle/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I looked at the example and from what I see, it will give me a box for the entire paragraph. I want to extract a horizontal box for each sentence. I have also looked at 'Fourier Transform' before and I would be able to determine the image skew angle, but not extract the text lines.

Comment: You can determine the minimum rectangle for each of your contours (WORDS), too. Just utilize minAreaRect method for your point sets. If you are looking to extract the SENTENCES, well it is a little bit harder -you need to detect dots.